# $\mathbb{E}[f \mathbb{1}_{[0,\theta]}]=0$ for all $\theta \geq 0$ implies that $f=0$ almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

my question is essentially in the title.
Do we have for a function on the nonnegative real line, if for all $\theta\geq 0$ we have

$$
\mathbb{E}[f \mathbb{1}_{[0,\theta]}]=0
$$

then $f$ must be $0$ almost surely?

I would think so since the intervals $[0,\theta]$ generate the Borel sigma algebra for the nonnevative real numbers but I can't find the rigorous argument.

Any tips on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is tagged probability theory, but it seems that you work with the Lebesgue measure on the positive real line. Therefore, the expectation should be replaced by an integral. Moreover, it seems that you need to assume your function $f$ to be at least locally integrable for the integral to make sense. Once this is fixed, you can use the fact that an open set can be expressed as a countable disjoint union of open intervals hence the integral of $f$ over each open set vanishes.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo What makes you think this is the Lebesgue measure? I believe it can be a probability measure defined on $[0,\infty)$ with the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: @Mark: this is only a guess; indeed it could be a priori any probability measure, which would justify the tag.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo in fact it could be any probability measure on the nonnegative real line. However, for my issue also just the integral w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure would be enough since I work with densities w.r.t. Lebesgue. I didn't write an assumption on $f$ since I wanted to point out the core of the problem. Also for me an expected value is only allowed to be written down if it makes sense, to $f$ has to be at least locally integrable. For my question also integrable is just fine. How do I know that if it vanishes over each open set that it equals $0$?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the setting of the question, we assume that for each $t\geqslant 0$,
$$
\tag{*}\int_{[0,t)}f(x)g(x)dx=0
$$
where $g$ is a non-negative integrable function and $f$ is such that $\int_{[0,t)}\lvert f(x)\rvert g(x)dx$ is finite for each $t$.

First, (*) can be extended to finite disjoint union of open intervals, then to countable disjoint unions of such intervals. Any open set can be expressed as a countable disjoint union of disjoint intervals. Consequently, for each open set $O$,
$$\tag{**}
\int_{O}f(x)g(x)dx=0.
$$
Define the measure
$$
\mu\colon B\mapsto \int_{B}\lvert f(x)\rvert g(x)dx.
$$
For any fixed $R$, $\mu$ is a finite measure on $[0,R]$. One can show that the collection of sets
$$
\mathcal A:=\left\{B\in\mathcal B([0,R]):\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists F\mathrm{ closed, }O \mathrm{ open }, O\subset B\subset F, \mu(F\setminus O)<\varepsilon\right\}
$$
it a $\sigma$-algebra containing open sets. Using this, we extend (**) to Borel sets and we conclude that $f=0$ a.s. for the measure having density $g$.